# PHP Fetch data with two different function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question for this, maybe I am doing the wrong way
as I have created a  two different search function which they have own different function search
as one is SKU and one is Date

[image: search]

I have created a code for MySQL and Workbench and it working fine as I'm using

```
SELECT 
    settlement_id, sku
FROM
    settlements
WHERE
    sku LIKE 'ISCE%' 
        AND settlement_id LIKE '7072432852'
GROUP BY sku
HAVING sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0
ORDER BY sku
```

and it displayed fine

[image]

I use this same function for the PHP pages

```
$output = '';
if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["query"]);
    $queryskulist = "
    SELECT
        settlement_id,
        sku,
    FROM settlements
    WHERE sku LIKE '%" . $search . "%' and settlement_id LIKE '%" . $search . "%'    
    GROUP BY sku 
    HAVING sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0
    ORDER BY sku
    ";
} else {
    $queryskulist = "
    SELECT 
        settlement_id,
        sku,
    FROM settlements 
    GROUP BY sku 
    HAVING sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0
    ORDER BY sku  ";
}
```

as you can see

```
WHERE sku LIKE '%" . $search . "%' and settlement_id LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
```

that's where I am getting an error as I am able to get data from only one function like this

```
WHERE sku LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
```

but I am unable to get two different search result, should I use two different query $_POST["query"]?

Any advice would be great, or Sample/Example demo PHP site would be great, it would help me a big picture on it.

Comment: why you are usinh having without aggreagation function ?

Comment: "I have created a code for MySQL and Workbench and it working fine as I'm using " `SELECT 
    settlement_id, sku .... GROUP BY sku` is a invalid use of GROUP BY read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: a great document to read it, thanks as I am still learning all MySQL stuff. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the update, I have fixed this issue as I have decided to remove 'Sku' and keep the rest of it, so here is what happened.

'Settlement_id' is used an options dropdown value on the PHP pages which they are pulling data from MySQL and the 'SKU' search box are using on the input box. and the input box is using Javascript Ajax Filters to get data which it displayed result from 'Settlement_Id' data

here is a demo
http://amazonsettlement.ishka.ie/MultiSelect/

Answer (score 2):

do the fact you have not aggregation function you should use where

```
    SELECT 
    settlement_id
    , sku
FROM  settlements
WHERE sku LIKE 'ISCE%' 
        AND settlement_id LIKE '7072432852'

WHERE sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0
ORDER BY sku
```

the use of group by  without aggreagtion function is deprecated  in SQL  .. and in the most recent version of mysql is not allowed .. (by default)

using group by without aggregation function you could obtain unpredictable result

Comment: "the use of group by without aggreagtion function is deprecated in SQL .. and uin the most recent version of mysql is not allowed .. " really? thats nice do you have a valid source for this?

Comment: mysql 5.7  doc  .. @RaymondNijland

Comment: Well read throuh all the links on this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html could not find annything related to the deprecation claim where i would expect it to be... Also looked under https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html where they summarize what has been added to, deprecated in, and removed from MySQL 5.7.. Couldn't find annything.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by using the following

```
SELECT
    settlement_id,
    sku
FROM
    settlements
WHERE
    (CONCAT(sku, settlement_id) LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
AND
    sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0
ORDER BY
    sku
```

Alternatively you should be able to wrap in parenthesis

```
WHERE (sku LIKE '%" . $search . "%') OR (settlement_id LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
```